# Removing data rows depending on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `subjects_to_exclude` which looks something like this:

```
    STUDY_ID
0   3
1   7
2   12
3   25
4   29
```

and another dataframe `cleaned_bp`:

```
    STUDY_ID    SBP     DBP     VISITCODE
0   1          145.0    91.0    1
1   2          139.0    92.0    2
2   3          141.0    88.0    3
3   4          135.0    92.0    6
```

And I want to remove the rows which have `STUDY_ID` values that are in `subjects_to_exclude`. Should I iterate through the all `cleaned_bp` multiple times and find a match in `STUDY_ID` values? (which would be an insufficient way to solve it) Is there a better solution?

Comment: Use `cleaned_bp = cleaned_bp[~cleaned_bp.STUDY_IDisin(subjects_to_exclude.STUDY_ID)]`, it is dupe :(

Comment: @jezrael oh thanks. Couldnt find that question since I did not know about `.isin()`

Comment: No problem, good luck!